# Bells whenever I double press space

Tags: vim

New to vim and I tried to setup space to be my leader key. However whenever I try to double press it for easymotion it just rings the alarm. Is there a good way to diagnose what is causing the issue? Thanks.

```
"-----------------------
" Vim-plug auto download
if empty(glob('~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim'))
silent !curl -fLo ~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs
\ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
autocmd VimEnter * PlugInstall --sync | source $MYVIMRC
endif
"---------------------:
"Vim plug plugins
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')

Plug 'easymotion/vim-easymotion'

call plug#end()

"---------------------------------------------------
set nocompatible " be iMproved, required
filetype off " required

"-------------------------------------------
" Automatic reloading of .vimrc
autocmd! bufwritepost .vimrc source %

syntax on "turns on the inbuilt syntax highlighting

" Better copy and paste
set pastetoggle =<F2>
"set clipboard = unnamed

set mouse=a "enables mouse scroll in vim
set bs=2 "normal backspace

set incsearch "enables partial searches

"Rebind leader key
nnoremap <Space> <nop>
let mapleader =" "
"map <Space> <Leader>

"quicker to use vim commands
nnoremap ; :

"faster navigation
nnoremap H ^
nnoremap L $
nnoremap J 5j
nnoremap K 5k

"add back join lines
nnoremap <leader>j J

"Fast Esc for insert mode
:inoremap jk <Esc>
:inoremap kj <Esc>

"Better window navigation
nnoremap <C-j> <C-w>j
nnoremap <C-k> <C-w>k
nnoremap <C-h> <C-w>h
nnoremap <C-l> <C-w>l


"----------------
"backups (double slash at end makes vim avoid name collisions)
"set backupdir=~/.vim/backup//
"set directory=~/.vim/swap//
"set undodir=~/.vim/undo//
```

Comment: have you tried opening vim with `vim -u NONE` and hitting double space to see if it still does it? opening it with -u NONE will open vim without your plugins and vimrc so you can help isolate the problem.

Comment: It really doesnt make sense to source your vimrc in a vimEnter autocommand—by that time, it’s already been sourced!

Comment: Thanks I didn't understand what you meant by source your vimrc?

Comment: Trying `vim -u NONE` gives an alarm after pressing single space (in normal mode) I don't know if that's normal or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Map your leader key to space with

`nnoremap <Space> <Nop>
let mapleader="\<Space>"`